# Group properties with same values in js

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object, each

I have a json like this that comes from a webservice

**JSON**

```
var json = `    
       {
        "78657": "AB4",
        "78658": "AB2",
        "78659": "AB4",
        "78660": "AB2",
        "78661": "ATS",
        "78662": "DECK",
        "78663": "DECK"
       }
`;
```

I want this to become an obj like the one below: properties with same values must be grouped in a way that the value becomes the value of "type" property, and the number of times this value is present in the original json must be reported in quantity:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var obj =
    {
        items:
        [
          {
            type: 'AB4',
            quantity: 2,
          },
          {
            type: 'AB2',
            quantity: 2
          },
          {
            type: 'ATS',
            quantity:1
          },
          {
            type: 'DECK',
            quantity:2
          }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner:

```js
var json = `    
       {
        "78657": "AB4",
        "78658": "AB2",
        "78659": "AB4",
        "78660": "AB2",
        "78661": "ATS",
        "78662": "DECK",
        "78663": "DECK"
       }
`;


console.log({items: Object.entries(Object.entries(JSON.parse(json)).reduce((prev, [,val]) => (
    prev[val] = (prev[val] || 0) + 1, prev
), {})).map(([type, quantity]) => ({ type, quantity }))});
```

Comment: wow this is superfast

Comment: can you please add a little of explanation? The solution proposed by konrad(the one without reduce) is clear to me, but this one with reduce is confusing me

Comment: @silvered.dragon the reduce simply builds a frequency object (it counts the number of times each element occurs).

Answer (score 2):

Perform a `reduce` the `Object.values()` of the input to form an index keyed by each value, counting as you go...

```js
const json = {
  "78657": "AB4",
  "78658": "AB2",
  "78659": "AB4",
  "78660": "AB2",
  "78661": "ATS",
  "78662": "DECK",
  "78663": "DECK"
};

const index = Object.values(json).reduce((acc, v) => {
  if (!acc[v]) acc[v] = { type: v, quantity: 0 }
  acc[v].quantity++;
  return acc;
}, {});
const obj = { items: Object.values(index) }
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: your code doesn't works in the snippet preview

Comment: @silvered.dragon - It looks like Konrad kindly repaired a typo.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const json = `    
       {
        "78657": "AB4",
        "78658": "AB2",
        "78659": "AB4",
        "78660": "AB2",
        "78661": "ATS",
        "78662": "DECK",
        "78663": "DECK"
       }
`;

const object = JSON.parse(json)

const data = {}

Object.values(object).forEach(key => {
  if (key in data) {
    data[key] += 1
  } else {
    data[key] = 1
  }
})

const list = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  type: key,
  quantity: value
}))

const final = {
  items: list
}

console.log(final)
```